# Is the noumena, in a sense apeiron?

Tags: kant, plato, ancient-philosophy

Consider Anaximanders *apeiron*, the indeterminate in the context of Platos theory of Forms; a form, an idea makes the indeterminate determinate in some particular way (In Anaximanders system - rotation ie generalised motion; in his system there is no linear motion - any motion being extended to infinity closes up or turns back)

In Kants system, identifying the *noumena* as *apeiron*; we have the Forms, time and space; they are pure intuitions being inseperable from us.

Is this then *hylomorphic* in Aristotles sense, as it appears inseperable from the *apeiron* (or *noumena*)?

Does this explain *noumena* as the *ding-an-sich* - the thing-in-itself, as it is the thing without the form and therefore indeterminate?

Does this solve the location of Forms? In Plato, a form exists in some intelligible realm; here we have a second hylomorphism where the pure intuitions of Time and Space are intrinsic to mind.

But then how does Kant solve the problem of universals for Time and Space?

Finally, is this consonance with Platos theory of Forms, and Anaximaders *apeiron* a figment of my imagination; or is there some corroborating literature that validates this view, implicitly or explicitly?

**note**

[apeiron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeiron_(cosmology)) is etymologically limitless (from [peirar](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=pei=rar) - limit) or indefinite [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=a) and in Patricia Curds book on the Pre-Socratics.

It's also attested as *arche* (first principle) in Simplicius's commentary to Aristotles *Physics*.

Comment: On this reading, it seems like you're conflating the noumenal with thing-in-itself, and that your claim better applies to the latter (which may or may not be the former -- currently debated point in Kant scholarship), but maybe I am misreading you.

Comment: @virmaior: ok, I didn't realise that they were distinct concepts; I was positing an identity with the apeiron, because of indeterminiteness; and with the thing-in-itself as something without a form; I suppose if I want to try to put some order into my thoughts here I'll have to look at some scholarship into how these two terms are theorised.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with aperion to competently answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The question “Is the noumena in a sense apeiron?” addresses topics from four different philosopher: Anaximander, Plato, Aristotle and Kant.

- Anaximander: Apeiron means “without boundary, infinite”. Speculating 
  about the primordial matter Anaximander stands in the tradition of
  Ionian philosophers of nature.  Unfortunately, we have only fragments
  from the work of Anaximander. Hence everybody is called on giving his
  own interpretation.  Apparently, Anaximander does not vote for
  creation ex nihilo, because he does not vote for creation at all.
  Instead his primordial unbound matter generates the cosmos by
  spontaneous self-organization. 
  **Note**: Apeiron does not mean “without form”. Nevertheless the    primordial matter seems to be unstructured, i.e. formless.
- Plato: Plato tries to reconcile his two forerunners Parmenides and
  Heraklit. They are considered antipodes. The first claims that
  insight can only be obtained from statements about immutable eternal
  objects, i.e. by detecting invariants. The latter is the proponent of
  a process based worldview. Heraklit claims that all objects change. 
  Platon proposes a dualistic worldview: With our senses we experience
  the world of change. But on a deeper level, by our intellect we
  detect the blueprint of the world of change. This blueprint is the
  realm of the ideas. Already Platon struggles with problems resulting
  from his ansatz to design ideas as analogue to material objects.
  E.g. how can many objects participate on the same idea, where are
  ideas located?
- Aristotle: The problems of Plato's theory of Forms have been expanded
  by Aristotle, e.g. Met. 990b ff.. Aristotle does not propose a
  solution to single problems because Aristotle rejects the whole
  theory of Forms.  The best answer I know, if someone asks where ideas
  are located: Ideas are patterns flexibly wired into the synaptical
  weights of our neural networks within the cortex.   Aristotle’s own
  contribution to explain the existence of objects is his theory of the
  four causes. One cause, the causa materialis, asks for the underlying
  matter (hyle) of the objects in question. In case of the universe,
  Anaximander probably would answer: The primordial matter is without
  form and bound, it is apeiron.
- Kant: He coins the term thing-in-itself and identifies it with the
  term noumenon. The term denotes the objects of the physical world. We
  must assume that such objects exist. Otherwise we cannot explain
  where the input to our senses comes from. But we do not have direct
  access and cannot know anything about a thing-in-itself.  What we
  call experience is an intellectual construct, built with the help of
  the two forms of perception, space and time, and the categories. 
  Because we cannot know anything about the thing-in-itself, Kant
  consequently avoids any positive statement about the thing-in-itself.
  In particular, he does not link it to Platonic forms.  The wording
  “noumenon” is misleading, because Plato considers the term in quite a
  different sense. Also the two forms of perception, space and time, do
  not belong to the domain of ideas considered by Plato.  I do not see
  a link between Kant’s forms of perception and the problem of
  universals.

Summing up, I do not see a relation between Anaximander’s apeiron and Plato's Theory of forms. Even less, I consider the three concepts apeiron, idea and thing-in-itself three different concepts, incomparable, unlinked, each on a different conceptual level. At the most, I consider *apeiron* a kind of *hyle*.

Comment: See note above; apeiron is etymologically boundless, but it has been attested as indefinite too ie without form.

Comment: Which I think you say in your entry on Anaximander as 'unstructured ie formless'.